# catching SocketException in socket.connectAysnc

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-phone-7, tcp

I am building an application for WP7. And I am working on etablishing a TCP connection

**code**

```
namespace TCP
{
   public class SocketEventArgsExtension : SocketAysncEventArgs
    {
      public EventHandler<SocketAysncEventArgs> _onConnectionCompleted;

      public OnCompleted(EventHandler<SocketAysncEventArgs> handler)
      {
         base.completed+=handler;
         _onConnectionCompleted=handler;
      }
    }
} 

 namespace TCP {
   public class TCPSocket: Socket
   {
       public TCPSocket():base(all arguments)         

       public bool ConnectAsync(SocketEventArgsExtension socketArgsExtension)
       {
         try{              
               if (!base.ConnectAsync(socketArgsExtension))
               {

         socketArgsExtension.SocketActionIfCompletedSynchronously(socketAsyncEventArgs);

               }
             }catch(SocketException e )
             {
                this.ConnectAsync(socketArgsExtension);
             }


        }

   }
}

namespace TCP
{
   public class connection
   {
     public void func()
     { 
        try
        {
           Socket s= new TCPSocket();
           var Socketargs= new SocketEventArgsExtension()  {RemoteEndPoint=_hostEntry};           //_hostEntry is DndEndPoint;
           socketArgs.Oncompleted((o,e)=>Somecallback(e));
           s.connectAsync(SocketArgs);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

Now my problem is When  I feed _hostEntry with a server address which does not exist And then try to debug

It throws an Exception

System.IO.FileNotFoundException

with details

{"File or assembly name 'System.Net.debug.resources, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e', or one of its dependencies, was not found."}

Now When I click  continue

again Exception occurs

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
  Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
  ErrorCode=10060
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoWSAConnectOrSendTo(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoWSAConnectByName(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.WSAConnectByNameAsyncRequest.doRequest()
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AsyncRequest.handleRequest()
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SocketAsyncRequestManager.WorkerThread.doWork()
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SocketAsyncRequestManager.WorkerThread.doWorkI(Object o)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

though I am catching Exceptions it does not go through the catch block.Rather prompts the above mentioned exceptions in dialog box.

While Debugging I have selected break when exception occurs

Comment: Doesn't the second exception go to your catch block when to press continue?

Answer (score 1):

After searching for the cause of error some of the forums suggest that the filenotfound exception is a bug in windows phone 7.1 debugging environment for socket connection.